# How to update unique fields using a confirm page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have this book edit page which contains unique fields(Title, ISBN). But  before I submit the form to update, I need to send first the form information to another confirmation page and then update. But when I pass the form info to the confirmation page, the unique validations for Title and ISBN fails. I have this code:

`book.rb`

```
  validates :title, presence: true,
                    uniqueness: true
  validates :isbn,  presence: true, 
                    uniqueness: true,
                    format: { with: /[0-9]/ }
```

`edit.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @book, url: confirm_edit_admin_book_path, method: :patch, html: { class: "form" } do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :id %>
        <div class="float-right">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
        </div>
        <h4 class="card-title">Edit Book</h4>
        <div class="form-group row mt-5">
            <%= f.label :title, class: "col-md-2 col-form-label required" %>

            <div class="col-md-10">
                <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
                <%= render "admin/shared/error_field", field: :title %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <%= f.label :isbn, "ISBN", class: "col-md-2 col-form-label required" %>

            <div class="col-md-10">
                <%= f.text_field :isbn, class: 'col-sm-12 form-control' %>
                <%= render "admin/shared/error_field", field: :isbn %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <%= f.label :released_at, class: "col-md-2 col-form-label required" %>

            <div class="col-md-10">
                <%= f.date_field :released_at, class: 'col-sm-12 form-control' %>
                <%= render "admin/shared/error_field", field: :released_at %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <%= f.label :description, class: "col-md-2 col-form-label" %>

            <div class="col-md-10">                       
                <%= f.text_area :description, class: 'col-sm-12 form-control' %>
                <%= render "admin/shared/error_field", field: :description %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <%= f.label :quantity, class: "col-md-2 col-form-label required" %>

            <div class="col-md-10">                       
                <%= f.number_field :quantity, class: 'col-sm-12 form-control' %>
                <%= render "admin/shared/error_field", field: :quantity %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="float-right">
            <%= f.submit "Confirm", class: "btn cur-p btn-primary" %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

`books_controller.rb`

```
def confirm_edit
  @book = Book.new(book_params)
  book_info = Book.find(@book.id)
  if @book.valid?
    session[:book_update] = @book
  else 
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def update
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  @book.update_attributes(session[:book_update].compact)
  session.delete(:book_update)
  redirect_to admin_book_url
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `confirm_edit` action you are creating a new instance of `Book` using the params from the update action, which are presumably the params from an existing book.

`@book = Book.new(book_params)`

You are then calling `@book.valid?` which is going to fail (unless you've changed the Title and ISBN) because a book with the same values is already in the database.

You could retrieve the book from the database and then use `.assign_attributes` to check validity that way perhaps?

```
def confirm_edit
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  @book.assign_attributes(book_params)
  if @book.valid?
    session[:book_update] = @book
  else 
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```